# Not being able to get Firebase user through StreamProvider

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-provider

I register the firebase user in my very first widget and try to access to it after signing in in the second screen. The result I got is null and I got this error: `Could not find the correct provider above this widget.` After researching, I still couldn't find the reason. I am guessing the context might be off somewhere, but still couldn't figure out why.

This is my first widget:

```dart
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Chat App',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
                visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
                inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                )),
                buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(buttonColor: Colors.blueGrey)),
            home: MultiProvider(providers: [
              StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
                value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
              )
            ], child: SignInPage()));
      }
    }
```

and this is the snippet of my second screen:

```dart
     RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Image.network(
                          'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-512.png',
                          width: 25,
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        'Sign In with Google',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        _progressBarActive = true;
                      });
                      FirebaseUser user =
                          Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context, listen: false);
                      await signInWithGoogle().then((value) {
                        print(value.uid);
    //                    print(user.uid);
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatRoom()));
                      }).whenComplete(() => {
                            setState(() {
                              _progressBarActive = false;
                            })
                          });
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

swap the `MultiProvider` with the `MaterialApp` :

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: SignInPage(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: try to use the `MultiProvider` as the first widget inside the `SignInPage` screen

Comment: Is it possible to call reload() for the firebaseuser? if not, do you know another way?